# Vertically center a text in a paragraph tag inside an 'absolute' positioned div

Tags: tailwind-css

There is main div

Inside it a 'relative' positioned div

then there are two tags img and then an overlay div, which has a p tag

I cannot vertically the text inside the p tag

[TailWind PlayGround of above work](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Eye8Ls4rZe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex property. Just add three classes to your absolute positioned div `flex items-center justify-center`.

Demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/bB6DKbVyi9